# Single Page contact form not showing

Tags: php, html, css

I have created a single page contact form source collected from online. The source uploaded working fine but edited as per my requirement not showing form in website.

I'm new to programming webdesign, i have attached the link.
[Single page inquiry form](http://www.bestwebconsultant.com/testmail/enquiry.zip)

I appreciate if some one help me to rectify the problem.

Comment: As if anyone will download and open your zip file. Not "moi" anyway. As an employer used to say when I asked for time off with pay: *Wish, are ya nuts?!* - Show your code in your question, NOT a zip file.

Comment: We can't "rectify the problem" if you won't describe the problem or demonstrate any information related to the problem.  A link to a file doesn't really provide any information.

Comment: Protip: Instead of a zip file, you should have made up a pastebin file. Visit http://pastebin.com and paste the link to that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on PHP errors to see what's going on there. It says:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/spoiledm/www/tv24.spoiledmilkclients.ch/enquiry.php on line 211
```

So, you opened curly bracket after `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')`, but never closed it.

Comment: I take it you opened the OP's zip file. I hope you have a very good anti-virus program installed on your computer. Zip files can contain and have been known to contain malicious code. You may not be so lucky next time. Do be careful.

Comment: It contained only single php file. You have to trust someone. :)

Comment: The OP could have easily made up a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) file instead. As I said, you may not be so lucky "next time". Some zip files are made that, as soon as you unzip it, the trojan does its work. I have been working with zip files since it's introduction way back when. I know what I'm talking about. As for trusting someone; believe me, people receive stuff they think just becomes it came from their mother or father, is safe.

Comment: `"It contained only single php file."` - That you know of.  `"You have to trust someone."` - By blindly opening that file, you're trusting *a lot* of people.  The user who uploaded it, the service that hosts it, the entire team that made the compression software you're using to open it, the team which defined the file format, your host OS, whoever maintains your patches and updates (do you?), etc.  "You have to trust someone" doesn't really hold up when you apply it to every user you encounter on the internet.